# Вызов template по результата условий

Tags: django

**вьюха №1**

```
def f_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)
    print(request.user)
    return render (request , "ffs.html", {})
```

которая прописана в urls

```
path('ferst/', f_view, name = 'f_fff'),
```

По которому рендерится определённый темплейт, в котором прописана такая форма. сначала идёт выпадающий список с двумя значениями. а в конце кнопка для отправки ответа.

```
<select class="title_name" name="title_name">
<option value="pst1"> New_fi </option>
<option value="pst2">New_fi_fi</option>
</select>

<form action="{% view new_creater%}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    id="submit" type="button" value="
</form>
```

первая вьюха рендерит страницу на которой я хочу что бы юзеру сначала предоставлялось одно поле с 2 переменными на выбор (в виде выпадающего списка). Он выбирал один из вариантов и нажимал на кнопку (которая указанная выше). По клику которая вызывала другую вьюху(в примере указана эта вьюха ниже) дананя вьюха проверяет условие которое указал пользователь и отрендерила определённый темплейт. Или можно что бы она вызывала определённую вьюху.

**Вьюха №2**

```
st1 = 'New_fi'
def new_creater(request):
    print(request.GET)
    print(request.POST)
    context = {}
    if st1 == request.POST.get('title_name'):
        return render(request, 'create_pdf.html' , context)
    else:
        return render(request , 'register.html', context)
```

в urls прописан такой путь

```
path('new_creater/', new_creater, name = 'creator_pdf'),
path('new_creater_v1/', new_creater, name = 'register'),
```

Comment: В чем вопрос-то?

Comment: это не работает. то что я написал. нужно что бы это работало. возможно я не правильно понимаю принцип работы. Или где то ошибся. Возможно у Вас есть лучше решение для представленной мною задачи

Comment: как вы определили, что это не работает? Какая ошибка? Что вы видите на экране?

Comment: нажатие на кпнку с 1 вьюхи должно перенаправлять на вторую вместе с параметрами, а вторая должна это учитывать. Вообще посмотреите в сторону WidardView

Comment: Не работает по двум причинам :
1. ошибка NoReverseMatch at /home/
Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

2. ничего не происходит по нажатию на кнопку